# what is the global variable name where regex matches are saved to?

Tags: javascript, regex

Previously used regular expressions.

```
/.*/.exec('meow')
```

{thingIforgot}[0] == 'meo'

Now I know that the above expression returns the results. I am specifically trying to remember the name of the variable that I cant google is.

==============================

```
 while((carry = /{[^%]\/*?\}/.exec(string))){
    var _results
    if(/\{s\d+\}/.exec(carry[0])){

    } else
    if(/\{s\d+\}/.exec(carry[0])){

    } else{
      throw new Error('MARLFOREMD STRING '+string)
    }
```

I know I don`t have to assign that expression = /

Comment: I have been searching for the name of that variable for 15 minutes it exists and it alows you to not have to make assignment in your if clause and use ternary statements with reg ex tests

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're asking or what would be expected for an answer. If you're looking for global variables related to RegExp (such as perl's `$&`, `$'`, etc.), JavaScript does not have equivalents. [`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns the match collection, which you'll need to store in your own variable. Or, are you wanting to know how to modify the pattern to create the expected match? Currently, it will match the entire string rather than just `'meo'`.

Comment: In javascript there is a variable that holds a back reference to the results of the previously executed regular expression. I am trying to recall the name of the reference, surprisingly it is not in the MDN. I believe some people see it as poor form.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for some deprecated Firefox functionality:

> **Gecko 8.0 note (Firefox 8.0 / Thunderbird 8.0 / SeaMonkey 2.5)**
>
> Prior to Gecko 8.0 (Firefox 8.0 / Thunderbird 8.0 / SeaMonkey 2.5), exec()
> was implemented incorrectly; when it was called with no parameters, it
> would match against the value of the previous input (RegExp.input
> property) instead of against the string "undefined". This is fixed;
> now /undefined/.exec() correctly results in ['undefined'], instead of
> an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Calling_exec()_with_no_parameters_in_old_Gecko_versions

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a few other languages, [especially Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions), JavaScript/ECMAScript does not have global variables associated with RegExp matching.

The information about the previous match is stored only in the returned value/collection and in properties [on the `RegExp` itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex):

```
var pattern = /./g;
var found = pattern.exec('a');

console.log(found[0], found.index, pattern.lastIndex); // "a", 0, 1
```

Though, note that the `lastIndex` will only increment for "*global*" `RegExp`:

```
var pattern = /{[^%]\/*?\}/g;
//                         ^

while((carry = pattern.exec(string))){
    // ...
}
```

You can see everything that `.exec()` does [in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.6.2).